# ruby gem or rails tips on how to use xmlrpc server/ weblog api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-rpc

i am trying to get my rails app interfacing with blogging clients. first of all i am not sure which one to choose from (metaweblog, wordpress, movabletype, atompub). second, is there any tutorial on how to implement such a XMLRPC (or similar) server with rails 3?
any ideas?

i just came across old posts on how to use the xmlrpc/server lib from ruby-core, but i think maybe there are other ways to achieve the same here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with some RESTful external api's, just use [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html).

You can find a great railscast about this:

[ActiveResource Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics)

[More on ActiveResource](http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource)